# Error al realizar migrate en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Al tratar de realizar migrate aparece el siguiente error:

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Renaming the 'clientes_empregado' table while in a transaction is not supported on SQLite because it would break referential integrity. Try adding `atomic = False` to the Migration class.
```

Realice makemigrations y migrate varias veces.
Me fijé que el proyecto que estoy siguiendo (videotutorial) utiliza versión de Django 2.1 y antes utilicé la versión 2.2, pero mismo con el downgrade de versión persiste el error.

Elimine la base de datos: db.sqlite3, pero volvió a generar error al hacer migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes eliminar las migraciones y hacer makemigrations , y también verificar si la atomisidad es soportada por sqlite.

Comment: @op resolvió tu problema? (A todo esto, ¿como cito al creador de esta pregunta con @?)